# Website doesn't find stylesheet in Safari/IE

Tags: css, safari

No idea why this is happening... this is what it looks like in firefox:

[image]

And this is what it looks like in Safari:

[image]

A quick inspection with firebug for safari shows that its not picking up any style sheets except transmenu.css (for the menu - which isnt' even being used). I can't find ANY reason why this would happen.

Any ideas?

website: http://tradartsteam.co.uk

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but is there a reason why you're loading those style sheets so late in the game? (In the bottom half of the document)

Comment: bottom half of what? I'm loading them at the bottom of the head. They were loaded at the top, but then I thought that something might be getting in the way someway down the document, so I moved them down just to make sure it wasn't something silly like that.

Comment: oh, indeed, they're still in the head! Disregard what I said. Although if you're using them on every page, it might be useful to put those scripts into an external file to reduce loading times

Comment: haha... :) thats ok :) yeah, it might be an idea, for now though, need to know why safari doesn't like me. :(

Comment: moving the style sheet loading back up to the top changes the layout of the website slightly... :/ again, no idea why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Thomas Clayson: Remove the extra `</script>` on Ln. 35 of your source-code.

**Edit**: It's two lines after `<script type="text/javascript" src="/_common/js/mootools-1.2-more.js"></script>`

**Update**:
@Thomas Clayson: The only way I could get the page to display just fine was to comment out the entire `<script>` element with `$.noConflict();` inside until before `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/swfobject.js"></script>`. Even just `$.noConflict();` on its own breaks the page again. I'll do some more digging and update my answer again (unless someone else can find the solution before me).

**Super Massive Update**: @Thomas Clayson: After going a little batty that I couldn't see/find the problem, I set about making the document compliant for its `DOCTYPE` using the [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org/)...that eventually and finally led me to the offending code hidden deep within the `events` of `$('#calendar').fullCalendar`!

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> <w:WordDocument> <w:View>Normal</w:View> <w:Zoom>0</w:Zoom> <w:PunctuationKerning /> <w:ValidateAgainstSchemas /> <w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>false</w:SaveIfXMLInvalid> <w:IgnoreMixedContent>false</w:IgnoreMixedContent> <w:AlwaysShowPl...
```

Not only is it horrible, proprietary MS Word nonsense, it got truncated and well...it severely messed with your site in some unexpected (at least by me) ways. Ah, even though your comment below pointing out what I should have felt in my bones having had to deal with this very issue far too many times before myself came a little late, your question has ultimately given me valuable experience so +1 for that. ;-)

Comment: removed it... it didn't have any effect. :( thanks for finding that though - wrong side of a php if loop.

Comment: thanks for your update. You're right... the problem was we have a WYSIWYG editor in the administration panel of the CMS and the client had copied and pasted from word into that which had messed up something. :) no idea what was causing it not to work on safari, but on firefox... but it works now. :) thanks

Comment: @Thomas Clayson: Firefox just seems to be a little too lenient... I'd prefer it if all browsers coughed and spluttered at the injustice of having to render something that got pasted in from MS Word. Maybe that might finally get people to stop doing it. Oh well, glad you tracked down the issue and sorry for my initial ineffectual answers.

Comment: haha, its ok - the problem is with things like this its very difficult to know where to start, and debugging is a long complicated process. Console errors are all well and good but they only point out that there IS a problem, and not where or what that problem might be! :p the truncation was a bad idea, it was just a simple substr which was frequently breaking html tags, so I've stripped tags and removed the MSWord nonsense, so hopefully it should work now! :p Thank you very much for your help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Safaris web inspector shows errors.  Ignore the favicon, but I suppose it might have something to do with that.[image]

In fact, just having looked more closely at your source code, I found a great number of mismatched opening and closing tags, especially within the abbreviated text strings in your jQuery javascript (the ones ending on "...") - whatever you did to parse those even cut some of the tags in half.

I don't know how Firefox tolerates this (quite amazing, actually), but you might want to check your document syntax from top to bottom and make sure your code is correct.  I'm quite sure Safari is not the only browser bound to have problems with this page.

Comment: how do you get to the web inspector in safari?

Comment: Just edited the original answer.  You really want to check your code.

Comment: yeah... just needed a strip_tags php function. :) that's not the problem, but thank you for pointing that out... not my javascript code you see.

Answer (score 0):

Link to your stylesheet before your scripts (even better - put your scripts at the bottom of the page.)

I'm not sure exactly what the problem is but you do have an awful lot of javascript and the errors look to be interfering with the page load.

Comment: yeah, javascript's not all mine... i'm just trying to find out why the page wasn't loading properly! :p

Comment: Oh yeah,  been there before! Might have been better to put this as a comment rather than an answer. If you are able to restructure the order of your scripts and stylesheets I advise you to. The page will still obtain the correct layout (and sooner)  in case of script errors. Reckon this is especially important with 3rd party code :)

Comment: I will look into it, or at least for our future sites! :) thanks for the advice